# SQL Server Agent - Running SSIS Package with Proxy

Tags: ssis, permissions, sql-server-agent

I have followed the below article to create credentials/proxy to run a SSIS job from SQL Server Agent.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

I get this error:
*Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Could not get proxy data for proxy_id = 6).  The step failed.*

Does the credential account need to be a Domain user account? I have tried using sa and another SQL Login but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the post is old, but to make this work be sure that the user you set as Run As in the Job, has access to the proxy and is in the list of the proxy Principals. If the user is systemadmin in sql it will not get saved in the list and you will get the error.